# Does the outcome of conference championship games affect College Football Playoff standings?

Tags: american-football, collegiate

With the "regular" season of NCAA football over, are the College Football Playoff standings locked, or are the outcomes of the various conference championship games considered when determining the final CFP standings? I'm specifically interested in regards to the playoffs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the final College Football Playoff standings take in account conference championship games.

The [College Football Playoff Selection Committee Protocol](https://collegefootballplayoff.com/sports/2016/10/24/selection-committee-protocol.aspx) places an emphasis on conference championships won. A non-champion may be selected in the case that that team is "unequivocally one of the four best teams in the country".

In 2014, in the first year of the CFP rankings, Ohio State moved from #5 in the rankings (in Week 15) to #4 in the rankings after beating Wisconsin in the Big Ten championship game.